# JTextPane: What's the renderer of/for setCharacterAttributes?

Tags: java, jtextpane, renderer

I have a JTextPane in my application and I prepare some styles for various words/letters. These styles are applied via `setCharacterAttributes`. Now I plan to style the background of some styles: If a style defines a background (say gray) and I want to soften the corners (round corners with ie. 3px).

Is there a way to add a special renderer that is used within setCharacterAttributes? Or, do you recommend `HighlightPainter` added via `pane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(...)`?

Comment: You are planning to soften the corner of characters ??

Comment: @Sharcoux: Nope, I plan to have a background (say gray) with black font. The background should have lovely round corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Your question is not very clear, but if I understand correctly, you intend to customize the default behaviour of the background properties on characters. You describes 2 approaches, and one is probably much easier than the other one.

1) Based on Character attributes (complex one) : You need to define your behaviour by overriding the `paint` method in `javax.swing.text.GlyphView`. Then, you will need to change the ViewFactory of your EditorKit to make it take your change into account. I would not recommend this approach.

2) Based on Highlights (easier one) : You need to define a new `javax.swing.text.Highlighter.HighlightPainter` that paints the round borders as you wish. Then you need to find every set of text where a background is set. You remove the background and add your custom highlighter instead. You can optimize the process, but I think you already got this part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go for the 2nd solution. The first solution sounds cumbersome but very professional. Next time I will try to add an image.